Tailwind css responsiveness not working in angular 18
I am using Angular 18 with tailwind CSS.
For mobile view, I want both the columns to have full width but it is not working.
Any help is appreciated.
<div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 mt-5 min-h-[calc(100vh-190px)]" *ngIf="isReady">
        <div class="col-span-2 !sm:col-span-5 panel p-0 bg-yellow-50 border border-yellow-300">
// customer details goes here
        </div>
        <div class="panel col-span-3 !sm:col-span-5 p-1">
            <app-interaction-history [interactionHistory]="interactionHistory"
                [selectedCustomer]="selectedCustomerDetails"></app-interaction-history>
        </div>
</div>

I tried using flex but to no avail.
I also tried adding sm:grid-cols-1 to the main grid but still does not work

try with these two: for the first div col-span-5 sm:col-span-2 and for the second div col-span-5 sm:col-span-3

@robert Thanks a lot! Finally I got it to work. Now I understood that we need to define classes for smaller screens first and then go upwards for larger screens
